# computing differential equation using general solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$\require{cancel}$$

Given equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}y=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
Integrating factor:
$$e^{\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}dx}=e^{-\ln|\cos(x)|}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
Multiply the equation with integrating factor gets
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{\cos(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)}$$

$$\rightarrow \cancel{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}y=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}$$

$$\rightarrow \cancel{y=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}$$

correction:

Integrate both sides get:

$$\rightarrow \frac {y}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)+C$$

$$\rightarrow y=\frac{\sin(x)(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}+C\cos(x)$$

$$\rightarrow y=\sin(x)+C\cos(x)$$

this is so far my steps for computing the solution, can anyone verify my step if there's any mistake?

Comment: One way to do so, and is pretty easy to do is to plug your $y$ into the original ODE. (I have not done this for you to say yes or no)

Comment: With regards to what Chinny64 just said, it's very to see that you're solution doesn't work. as it would lead to $y'$ being the null function.

Comment: accidentally derived lhs instead of integrate both sides, corrected the equation and thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not understand the last $2$ steps. The steps, in any case, should have been -
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{\cos x}\right)=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$
or,$$d\left(y\sec x\right)=\sec^2 x dx$$
or,$$\int d\left(y\sec x\right)=\int \sec^2 x dx$$
or,$$y\sec x=\tan x +c_1$$
or,$$y=\sin x + c_1\cos x$$